# Groupby with agg with row based condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, null, aggregate

I have to merge all duplicate values in a dataframe with each cell's value seperated by a comma. The problem is that I don't want the na values to be grouped together which are present in string format (nan is present in 'nan' format), so,i can't simply use df.groupby(['column']).agg(', '.join)

I tried using df.query and filtered the string format of nan values but then they all got filtered out, what i need to do is to treat them differently.

By now what i am able to do is,

`df = df.groupby(['TIN', 'PIN']).agg(', '.join).reset_index()`

Here, i got the result as,

```
    PIN    TIN    Column
0   1      2,4    a,b,c
1   3      1,7    d
2   nan    8      e,f
3   nan    nan    g,h,i,j,k,l,....
```

What i needed was:-

```
    PIN    TIN    Column
0   1      2,4    a,b,c
1   3      1,7    d
2   nan    8      e,f
3   nan    nan    g
4   nan    nan    h
5   nan    nan    i
6   nan    nan    j
7   nan    nan    k
8   nan    nan    l 
.......
```